# Saving custom object programmatically in salesforce

Tags: object, salesforce

I defined a custom object (called Transaction). I populated it within a trigger. The trigger is defined after insert of Task object. After populating Transaction object i want to save it such that it shows up as a object of type Transaction in  data management->storage usage.

How do i do this?

The only way I have saved custom objects  is by using dataloader to import them. Not sure how to save them directly from within Sdfc apex code.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

regards
Sameer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if understand correctly, but in trigger You probably got something like this:

```
Transaction__c trans = new Transaction__c();
trans.Some_Field__c = 'some value';
```

And after that You should have add:

```
insert trans;
```

Hope that helps